Interface between Material studio and LAMMPS
How can I utilize output files (XYZ format) from LAMMPS in Materials Studio?
How can I calculate the UV-visible spectrum in Materials Studio using the XYZ format extracted from LAMMPS software?
Is this possible? Tnx.

+1. Welcome to our community!

Material Studio is a suite of several types of software. It has tools for quantum calculations, classical and mesoscale simulations, and statistical analysis together with crystallization tools.
For UV-visible spectrum calculations, you need to use one of the available quantum tools:

Materials Studio provides a range of density functional theory based solvers and semi-empirical methods to predict properties of
molecular and solid state materials from electronic structure, It also includes specialized solvers for using quantum mechanical derived
energies and properties in chemical reaction.

Some of them are:

CANTERA
CASTEP
DMol3
DFTB+
ONETEP

Be aware that as Material Studio is a suite, you will need to pay for each tool separately.
If you used LAMMPS in your previous calculations, I will assume that your system is "big" (more than 200 atoms). If it is the case, the use of quantum tool can be difficult.
Finally, I am not sure if Material Studio can import XYZ files, but this can be fixed using package like OpenBabel and converting XYZ to other formats like MOL, SDF or MOL2.
